# What is optimal db setup for flutter app?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, back4app

I'm developing an app with flutter, where the app needs access to a db with text/pictures (think, say, 2,000 different food recipes although it's not another recipe app). About once weekly, recipes need to be added by app-developer but never by the user, so it's a one-way street.

It's not so time-critically in terms of how fast db updates are distributed to the app users. What is more critical, is that the users have a fast experience browsing through recipes.

The app also needs authentication, notifications etc.

I'm really struggling with the best way to set this up without it getting too complicated. I'm thinking the best setup would involve the db being transferred to client at installation or first launch and then continuously updated from the server. This would minimize traffic and maintain (fast) local access to the data.

I guess the db could work with both NoSQL and SQL, since it's fairly simple.

I've considered using Firebase/Firestore for everything. The way it would work is with a hosted NoSQL db and then a db cache on the clients. However, I'm reading that I can't manage the cache very well with Firestore - for example I can't prepopulate the cache on installation (or alternatively on first launch) which I'm thinking would be needed for a fast user experience.

Is there an easy way to solve this with Firebase? Or is another BAAS, e.g. back4app, more suitable? Or am I thinking about this all wrong and should go for a different structure altogether?

Any leads are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#access-data-offline) might help you.

On the app start, just set it to local db and show the results. It will be fast.

Then, you can set it online again to fetch new recipes.

This way it will be fast and updated.

If you want more explanation, ping me in the comments.

Comment: Thanks @Kushal - I saw this option of enabling offline persistence, but as I understand it, the local cache will only include a certain piece of data after the user has retrieved the data once, so the first time will be slow. I could see some workarounds where you on installation (or first launch) set the cache size big enough to include the entire db and then use a query that just fetches all the data. And further weekly queries when new data has been added. It just doesn't seem to be a very elegant way of doing it.